# Driver install question

Tags: drivers, server, usb, ethernet

VERY new to all this.
Built a box to run Ubuntu server 12.04

During installation it would not automatically make a internet connection.
I figure  the new board needed to have drivers installed

Ubuntu Server is installed and reboots fine.

The box I built has no optical drive.

Can I copy the drivers to a USB stick and install that way?

If so please show me how.

Thanks in advance, THom

Comment: We need to know the type of the LAN chip. Please post the output of `lspci -nn`

Comment: found this http://www.twm-kd.com/linux/realtek-rtl81688111e-and-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Have the correct drivers on USB stick

Comment: tar -xvjf r8168-8.035.00.tar.bz2     file name is r8168-8.035.00 but I get can not open no such file

Comment: lspci -nn   RTL8111/8168B

Answer (score 0):

The correct method of installing the driver is the following:

`tar xvjf r8168-8.035.00.tar.bz2`

`cd r8168-8.035.00`

`sudo ./autorun.sh`

This script compiles the module `r8168` and installs it to the right place.
To check whether it' loaded, run:

`lsmod | grep r81`

Also, `ifconfig` should list a new `ethX` network interface.